# Eclipse errors and fails to open after installation

Tags: system-installation, eclipse

When I open eclipse after the installation setup, this massage is shown

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/shehab/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1579788578308.log
```

What is this error?

Comment: And what does the log file ´/home/shehab/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1579788578308.log´ say ?

Comment: You can do `cat /home/shehab/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1579788578308.log`, edit your question and and post the content of the logfile. That would help.

Comment: error to open eclipse after the install  and show the massege error An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/shehab/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1579815329810.log

Comment: @ShehapTarek Please see the first two comments. Could you kindly paste the content of the logs into your question? We can't look inside the file for you.